# sql search results by month in format 2010-04-01 10:40:20

Tags: mysql, sql

How can i select all rows where the month is 04 from 2010 where the format of the date column is as follows: 2010-04-01 10:40:20 using mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [MONTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) AND [YEAR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) functions :

```
SELECT * FROM
table
WHERE MONTH(date) = 4 AND YEAR(date) = 2010
```

Answer (score 3):

assuming your field is a timestamp, you could use

```
select * from mytable where year(thefield)=2010 and month(thefield)=4;
```

or

```
select * from mytable where thefield between '2010-04-00' and '2010-04-30 23:59:59';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from month where month(my_date_column) = 4 and year(my_date_column) = 2010
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name`
WHERE YEAR(`date_column`) = 2010
AND MONTH(`date_column`) = 4
```

I don't know if this is the best way... but it should work!